# Haskell: URL encoding for post data

Tags: haskell, post, url-encoding

I've been looking at [`Network.HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.3/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html), but can't find a way to create properly URL encoded key/value pairs.

How can I generate the post data required from `[(key, value)]` pair list for example? I imagine something like this already exists (perhaps hidden in the `Network.HTTP` package) but I can't find it, and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [`urlEncodeVars`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.3/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Base.html#v%3aurlEncodeVars).

```haskell
urlEncodeVars :: [(String, String)] -> String
```

```haskell
ghci> urlEncodeVars [("language", "Haskell"), ("greeting", "Hello, world!")]
"language=Haskell&greeting=Hello%2C%20world%21"
```

Comment: Oops, missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to HTTP POST data `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `urlEncodeVars` may not be the right choice. The `urlEncodeVars` function does not conform to the [application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) in two ways worth noting:

- it encodes a space as `%20` instead of `+`
- it encodes `*` as `%2A` instead of `*`

Note the comment alongside the function in [`Network.HTTP.Base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.3/docs/src/Network-HTTP-Base.html#urlEncodeVars):

```
-- Encode form variables, useable in either the
-- query part of a URI, or the body of a POST request.
-- I have no source for this information except experience,
-- this sort of encoding worked fine in CGI programming.
```

For an example of a conformant encoding, see [this function](https://github.com/hspec/hspec-wai/blob/master/src/Test/Hspec/Wai/Util.hs#L37) in the `hspec-wai` package.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying `wreq` for this. It provides `FormParm` data type, so you would want to convert your key-value pairs into `[FormParm]`. Then you can use something like this:

```hs
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8
import Network.Wreq (post)
import Network.Wreq.Types (FormParam(..))

myPost = post url values where
  values :: [FormParam]
  values = [C8.pack "key" := ("value" :: String)]
  url = "https://some.domain.name"
```